# Haml Radio Button Pre-select Syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, radio-button, haml

We use Ruby (1.9.2) Rails (2.3).

I'm trying to set pre-selection for radio buttons...

```
- form_for @user, :url => plan_user_url, :html => { :method => 'put', :class => 'form' }  do |f|
  - @plans.each do |p|
    %span
      %p= p[:blurb]
      %p= p[:price]
      - p[:features].each do |f|
        %p= f
      = f.radio_button {:id => p[:id], :checked => @user[:plan_id]==p[:id] || nil}
      = f.label :plan_name, p[:name]
    %p
      %br
  .spacer

  .field.first
    = f.submit 'Update', :class => 'button ok'
  .field
    = link_to 'Cancel', redirect_back_url || root_url, :class => 'button cancel'
```

HAML doesn't like this line:

```
  = f.radio_button {:id => p[:id], :checked => @user[:plan_id]==p[:id] || nil}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Thanks for the hints from Brian.  It turns out

```
f.radio_button :plan_id, p[:id]
```

works for pre-select.

Answer (score 11):

This is invalid Ruby code:

```
= f.radio_button {:id => p[:id], :checked => @user[:plan_id]==p[:id] || nil}
```

You're attempting to call the `radio_button` method and Ruby thinks you're passing it a block, but really you're passing it a `Hash`. This is better:

```
= f.radio_button :id => p[:id], :checked => @user[:plan_id]==p[:id] || nil
```

That removes the ambiguity between `Proc` and `Hash`, but it's still weird. Why do you want the `|| nil`? I think it's unnecessary:

```
= f.radio_button :id => p[:id], :checked => @user[:plan_id] == p[:id]
```

Comment: Thanks, Brian.  I see what you're saying.  I tried what you suggested and got this

    Showing app/views/users/plan.html.haml where line #22 raised:

    wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)


    20:           - p[:features].each do |f|
    21:             %p= f
    22:           = f.radio_button :id => p[:id], :checked => @user[:plan_id] == p[:id]
    23:           = f.label :plan_name, p[:name]


Any ideas?

Comment: A `radio_button` call has to map to a value on whatever object the `form_for` call used, so it looks like you want `f.radio_button :plan_id`.

Comment: Yes, f.radio_button :plan_id, p[:id] works for pre-select!  Thanks, Brian.